# VBMath using / equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to use something like `VBMath.Randomize();` and `VBMath.Rnd();`

In C#, I tried with `using Microsoft.VisualBasic;`

But this doesn't work

Comment: can u share the error trace..

Comment: Are you looking for the [Random class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx)? (First result for "random c#" in google btw)

Comment: VbMath dont exist in current context. @Sayse : No, Vbmath function

Comment: then maybe you are looking for [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k47wsahf(v=vs.110).aspx) (first result for searching vbMath.randomize() in c#) Also, welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask]. Hint: Search before asking.

Comment: @Kylar - Add it to the context then, but the [documentation for `VBMath.Randomize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k47wsahf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states it just makes a random number generator - which .net already has a class for

Comment: @Zohar Peled : Already checked and tested... I searched before post.

Comment: @Sayse : I thought Random class work just with a min and max value, I will test it

Comment: `Rnd()` and `Randomize()` are legacy VB functions - even in VB apps it would be better to use the Net `Random` class

Comment: fk2 was right ! But yes, I will test with random class, why not, thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add Microsoft.VisualBasic as a reference to your Project. In your Project in the Solution Explorer right-click References and select "Add Reference". Search for "Microsoft.VisualBasic" in the Framework Tab.

Comment: Thanks !! It's perfect now !